# Looking for a book about a man who could change his looks

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

Back in school I read one book that caught my eye. It was about a man who could change his looks, nothing like werewolves or shapeshifters; he was described as having scars all over his form and would hide himself with a mask, or later on a mesh netting. He was an agent for the government or a special group. The most notable part of the book is the inclusion of the Nautilus submarine, an underwater base, and an invisible man. I don't remember the name of the book but this story has stayed with me for years and it annoys me that I can't remember the name.

Comment: When were you at school? The 1950's? The 2010's? It makes a difference.
It sounds a lot like The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen. But that was a comic, and then a movie, not a novel.

Comment: 2003 to about 2008 is when i read it. its one guy at first and meets a female companion

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: i can try to clarify the story better but i don't know if it will sound right, best i can remember is the final fight against the invisible man, in the underwater base they explain how the windows out are held down by water pressure, and the invisible man gets in the sub and hides then gets into the base and starts sabotaging it and the place starts flooding and the main character thinks of a way out and only comes with the idea to float with the water till they reach the window and float up with it to the surface, the invisible man attacks them in there and tries to drown him but he wins.

Answer (score 1):

Your character has many points in common with [the Avenger, by "Kenneth Robeson"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenger_(pulp-magazine_character)). There are several books in the series and one might well feature an underwater base.

The Avenger was involved in an accident that left him with white hair and completely pliable facial features. And being filthy rich, he goes Batman, founding a special group to fight crime, "Justice Inc.".

Comment: his appearance was caused by his ability to change his looks to be someone else.